# Complex xslt address splitting

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, split, xslt-1.0

I have an address that I need to be split after the first blank space (I think it's safe to assume that the street name starts after the first blank space). I need to then assign each section of text (street name/door number/P.O. Box) to different nodes. All punctuation also needs to be removed.

The code would need to take this:

```
<address>123 1st St., P.O. Box 321</address>
```

And turn it into this:

```
<door_num>123</door_num>
<street_name>1st St</street_name>
<addr_postfix>PO Box 321</addr_postfix>
```

I've seen several questions on how to split strings given a certain character or location within a string, but never using both parameters. I had initially thought to scan through the string and pick out any numbers, but I figured that this wouldn't work with P.O. Box numbers or numbered streets.

I'm thinking that I'll need to use the substring-before and substring-after operators, but I don't know how to properly implement them. Also, this is quite complicated and I don't even know where to start

Thanks,

Allen

Comment: Are you looking for a general purpose address parsing solution, or can we rely on things like the first space separating `door_num` from `streed_name` and `,` separating `street_name` from `addr_postfix`?

Comment: There won't always be a comma separating the address from the postfix (I used one to show that punctuation needs to be removed), but there will typically be a space separating the door_num from the street_name

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a complete transformation that works in the case of the provided XML document:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="address">
   <xsl:variable name="vNum" select="substring-before(.,' ')"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vStreet" select=
    "substring-before(substring-after(.,$vNum), ',')"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vPOBox" select="substring-after(.,',')"/>

   <door_num><xsl:value-of select="$vNum"/></door_num>
   <street_name>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate($vStreet, '.',''))"/>
   </street_name>
   <addr_postfix>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate($vPOBox, '.',''))"/>
   </addr_postfix>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<address>123 1st St., P.O. Box 321</address>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<door_num>123</door_num>
<street_name>1st St</street_name>
<addr_postfix>PO Box 321</addr_postfix>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, Dimitre. Unfortunately, I forgot to specify that the addr_postfix isn't always after a comma. Chances are, the address postfix will be separated by a space.

Comment: @AllenMcDonald, This is why both Mads and I say: "for *this* XML document". Do you realize that you haven't a well-defined problem? If so, this isn't problem at all -- the problem is to define the problem.

Comment: I do understand that I don't have a well defined problem, however I can't control what our customers give us as far as the format of the addresses. Some contain commas, some do not. I was tasked with separating the data, and I provided info to solve one example problem which will change. I apologize if I wasn't clear enough, but if I were to define every scenario, It'd be quite complicated and confusing.

Comment: @AllenMcDonald, this is the reason neither Google Maps, nor Bing Maps can interprete successfully *every* user-entered address -- nor the various public transit trip-planners. What you *can* do is to define the input syntax that you are going to accept and don't process input that you don't understand. Whenever you have that clearly-defined input that you want to process -- please, *then* ask a question. It is not desirable to post non-defined problems -- there is little if any benefit of trying to solve them as there always will be some "new, unspecified case".

Comment: I'll definitely take that into consideration. In addition to being new to XSLT/XML, I realized that this would be quite a difficult task to solve, and knew that I would not be able to solve it on my own...which is why I posted my problem here. I thank you for taking time to help me out, and would up-vote your current solution if I was allowed to.

Comment: @AllenMcDonald, An undefined problem is impossible to solve in *any* language -- not only in XSLT. If you come with fixed number of requirements, each represented by a corresponding input string and desired output (for that input), many people would be able to provide a solution. I believe that the real problem is that you cannot provide such fixed number of inputs and corresponding outputs. I would be glad to be proven wrong by your posting such a fixed set of (input, required output).

Comment: Dimitre, I can confidently say that the output will be the same in most cases (Punctuation removed, and door_num, street_name, and addr_postfix separated into different nodes), however I cannot guarantee the input format to be the same. Different customers might give us data with or without commas, semicolons, or periods, and due to the large number of addresses, we cannot change them to be the same. That is the purpose of this code- to sift through the many different combinations and return a uniform data format.

Comment: @AllenMcDonald, No code can solve an undefined problem -- if you cannot define a finite set of input types, then how would you expect someone to come up with an algorithm that works in all those undefined cases?

Answer (score 0):

This solves the specific case for the example address and could get you started:

```
<xsl:template match="address">
    <door_num>
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' ')"/>
    </door_num>
    <street_name>
       <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-before(substring-after(., ' '), ','), '.', '')"/>
    </street_name>
    <addr_postfix>
       <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space(substring-after(., ',')), '.', '')"/>
     </addr_postfix>
</xsl:template>
```